# .NET Execute a method for fixed 5 seconds and then stop

Tags: c#, .net, task

I want to read data on serial port using `SerialPort.ReadLine()` for exactly 5 seconds, and then stop reading. Currently I am using this code:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => { ReadSerial(); });    // this is the function that reads from serial port
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000); // I set the timeout period here. Like 5 seconds

if (!t.Wait(ts))                               // After 5 seconds, this runs
{
    port.Close();
    WriteToFile();
    t.Dispose();
}
```

Now, when executed once, it works perfectly fine. But if I execute it again in the same program, it never leaves the `Task t = Task.Run(() => { ReadSerial(); });` line.

So I am wondering if this is a good approach to do what I am trying to do, and what am I doing wrong here? Or if there is a better approach?

Comment: "But if I execute it again" - what is "it"?

Comment: The whole code block mentioned in my question. That is "it".

Answer (score 1):

The docs state the `By default, the ReadLine method will block until a line is received.` My guess is that the first time you are reading all of the data or a newline is never received. The blocking call never returns so you are stuck.

Try setting the `ReadTimeout` and handling the exception rather than attempting your own timeout.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: I set the timeout to a (reasonable?) 100 ms. But still it gets stuck on that exact function. Which is strange because I know for a fact that it is receiving data from the other side. Even when I pause it, it shows the data placed in the variable I assign it to.

Comment: The docs say `If a SerialPort object becomes blocked during a read operation, do not abort the thread. Instead, either close the base stream or dispose of the SerialPort object.` Without seeing more of the code I assume the `ReadLine` method is blocking. The `Task` classes share a thread pool to manage their activities so it could be blocked there. I would try disposing of the port and seeing if the read works again (for the second time) or use a real `Thread` and start the process that way (continuing with the `ReadTimeout` implementation from before).